# Spring CORS Mapping with '*' wildcard not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

I have a Spring Boot Application. In the Application class I define my CORS mappings like this:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/lists");
            }
        };
    }
```

Everything works with this, but when I want to add a mapping that contains e.g. an ID like this

```
registry.addMapping("/lists/**");  // it also doesn't work with '/lists/*'
```

, the mapping doesn't work anymore and I receive a "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header" error on a GET request like "/lists/142"

As shown in https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework , I have tried to use "/**" as a mapping to allow requests on all endpoint URLs, but only endpoints *without* dynamic values (e.g. IDs) seem to work fine.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use

```
@CrossOrigin
```

This works properly as wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "")
```

in your controller.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion! This seems to work, but it would be nice, if I could use the WebMvcConfigurer and the method addCorsMappings(), because I have to override this method with a certain logic and then apply it on the cors registry.

Comment: i tried to create an array in application.properties like 'allowedOrigins=http://localhost:1234,http://localhost:2345' and to refer to it in @CrossOrigin(origins = "${allowedOrigins}", but it doesn't work. it only works, if I specify just ONE element in allowedOrigins in the application.properties file. Is there a way properly load the ARRAY of properties into @CrossOrigin(origins = {..}) ?